# SQLBrowser not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, sqlbrowser

Let me explain my situation. So I installed a trial of SQL Server 2008.  The trial ran out and I  tried to go back the SQL Express install I had been use for 5 months with out an issue. I uninstall the features of Server 2008 and try to install SSMSE. I use SSMSE to change a password. I then get error 26 and trouble shoot. It turns out that SQLBrowser service for this database does not show up. I try creating a new db and I can't start the SQLBrowser for that database.  I can access the database locally and run queries on it. I know that you need to start SQLBrowser for SQL Express, I can't do this if there is no service to for the setting to change or on the SQLBrowser that is there I can't start it. So what did I due to SQLBrowser and how do I fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within express is not enabled by default:

Open the SQL Server Surface Area Configuration. On the SQL Server Surface Area Configuration page, click Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections. then click SQL Server Browser, click Automatic for Startup type, and then click Apply.

Now the service starts automatically every time that you start Microsoft Windows.

Comment: as I said I can't start the SQLBrowser I have.

Comment: My real problem is that there is no service for the database I need to run.

Comment: AFAIK SQL Browser service is not database service is a DBMS feature. If you have it installed and appears when you do services.msc then you should see the error once you look your OS log (while trying to start it). Otherwise if not present you should reinstall it.

Comment: Questions about tools and utilities related to programming are on-topic for Stack Overflow.